# How to query api gateway v2 stage id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, command-line-interface

I couldn't find any reference to it in the [aws cli docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/apigateway/get-stages.html). I need it, particularly for managing custom domain api mapping infrastructure using [this](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_api_mapping). Which enforces the management of the stage within the terraform with the same provider etc. as [this](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_stage) appears to be the currently only source I can find in order to fetch the "stage id".

I can see that [the cli depends on the name](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/apigatewayv2/create-api-mapping.html), but it appears as though the terraform provider isn't on par with this.

At any rate, I'd like to learn if that is possible or not even if it wouldn't solve my initial problem.